# AsyncHttpClient android internet issue

Tags: java, android, http

I’m new in android programming and for testing I have this code that download google home page.
The code works but I have a problem :

if I start app and internet is ok , code download without problem the page but if , for example , during download internet falls I have no way of knowing because no method will call.

How do I solve this problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();


        client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
                Log.d ("info", "PRIMA DELLA CONNESSIONE");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                Log.d ("info", "DATI");

                Log.d ("info", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                Log.d ("info", "errore");
                Log.d ("info", Integer.toString(statusCode));
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
                Log.d ("info", "RETRY");
            }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thats rigth thats how it works, but i think there is a method called,

onFinish, and you can set the request time, for some error of network connection you can put your code inside a try-catch

```
try
{
//your code here
}
catch(Exceptio e) // you can try catch SocketException
{}
```

with try you can catch if there is some error in your connection

Comment: first of this problem I noticed that when I start app and I haven’t internet connection AsyncHttpClient waits until internet connection will be available , but I would like that it executes onFinish method but I have to know that it goes in onFinish method because internet is not available